# Change the ID or URL of the Cloudfront Distribution to a Meaningful Name?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

In Amazon Cloudfront, the ID and the URL generated by the system look like a password, for example, DRGAT6N3K9NAP, it is too difficult to distinguish them if there are multiple distributions. It is possible to add a description for each Distribution, but there is a length limit.

So, is there a way to make the ID or the URL more meaningful or memorable? It is really a headache to see these password-alike IDs or URLs everyday.

Comment: I guess you could use tags for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't change it. it has a random name like that for security reasons also.

Why do you need to remember that ID/URL?

If you just do not want to see them, you can hide it. You can hide domain names by uncheck it from settings like the below image.
[image]

For ID, you need the browser extension to find and hide its element. But I don't know why do you headache see the IDs/Domains like that. I don't think it can hurt the brain or eyes by seeing it.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I want to distinguish between them easily.